# Jquery fails to Extract value into a textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 Buttons, on a click of a first button i want a value from a listbox to retrieve into textbox .
and click of a second button, the value from a textbox should clear.

this is how i have tried implementing the code, but it doesnt work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=BtnAddTokenValue.ClientID%>').click(function{
             var Value=$('#<%=ListBoxOptionValues.ClientID%>').find(':selected').val();
             $('#<%=TextBoxNameValue.ClientID%>').val(Value);

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=BtnRemoveTokenValue.ClientID%>').click(function(){
          $('#<%=TextBoxNameValue.ClientID%>').val("");
        });
    });
</script>




<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style3">
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnAddTokenValue" runat="server" Text=">" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNameValue" runat="server" Width="187px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style3">
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnRemoveTokenValue" runat="server" Text="<" />
                        </td>
</tr></table>
```

thanks for any assistence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you missed the `()` of first click function and its not necessary to call `doc ready` handler two times:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=BtnAddTokenValue.ClientID%>').click(function(){
         var Value=$('#<%=ListBoxOptionValues.ClientID%>').find(':selected').val();
         $('#<%=TextBoxNameValue.ClientID%>').val(Value);
    });

    $('#<%=BtnRemoveTokenValue.ClientID%>').click(function(){
      $('#<%=TextBoxNameValue.ClientID%>').val("");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
There was some minor error. I have corrected it.

Please see the below code

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=BtnAddTokenValue.ClientID%>').click(function (){
             var Value=$('#<%=ListBoxOptionValues.ClientID%>').find(':selected').val();
             $('#<%=TextBoxNameValue.ClientID%>').val(Value);

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=BtnRemoveTokenValue.ClientID%>').click(function(){
          $('#<%=TextBoxNameValue.ClientID%>').val("");
        });
    });
</script>



<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxOptionValues" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="add" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="clear" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style3">
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnAddTokenValue" runat="server" Text=">" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNameValue" runat="server" Width="187px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style3">
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnRemoveTokenValue" runat="server" Text="<" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
```